# Custom view calling canvas.draw causes crash with no error

Tags: android

I have a custom view in XML and when I use canvas.drawRect() outside of the onDraw() method it crashes and gives me no error except:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x98 in tid 26452
```

```
public class CustomLabelView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomLabelView";
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    public CustomLabelView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.standardGreen));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, mPaint);
        this.mCanvas = canvas;
    }

    public void drawLabel1(){
        Log.d(TAG, "drawLabel1: Called");
        mCanvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, mPaint);
    }
}
```

The method `drawLabel1()` is being called. However when `mCanvas.drawRect` is called it causes a crash.
If I don't call drawLabel1() and only call `canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, mPaint);` theres no crash and the rectangle is drawn. What causes this issue

Comment: The `Canvas` instance passed into `onDraw()` is only valid during that particular run of `onDraw()`. You can't use it outside of there.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a rectangle in this class everytime ```drawLabel()``` is called, but I'm unsure what to use for parameters of creating a ```new Canvas()``` . It's asking for a bitmap but what do I use to create that bitmap? Using no parameters doesn't draw anything onto the screen.

Comment: You need to structure your code so that all drawing operations happen during `onDraw()` (whether they're all directly inside that method, or in separate methods called from `onDraw()`). The `Canvas` passed into that method is what you need to draw to. If certain things are drawn conditionally, or with parameters that can change, then you'll need to maintain some sort of state – e.g., `private boolean doDrawLabelOne;` – to decide exactly what needs to be drawn, and how, in a given `onDraw()` run. The `invalidate()` method can be used to trigger a redraw when you modify the state. Follow me?

Comment: A little bit. I'm struggling to figure out how to structure the code so that when I hit a button from my mainactivity class, calls my instance of CustomLabelView class to draw the rectangle. Could it be that I'm instantiating the CustomLabelView class incorrectly, maybe I have to do it programmatically? I'm doing it in XML ```<e.com.test.customview.CustomLabelView/>``` The main confusion is how can I call that canvas inside ```onDraw()``` from my MainActivity class. I could only think of making the canvas a global variable, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I can put together a quick example to demonstrate, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, exactly. How is `CustomLabelView` meant to be used? Is there going to be one `CustomLabelView` for each label? Or can one `CustomLabelView` have multiple labels? I mean, is it supposed to add another label rectangle each time `drawLabel1()` is called? Or is it ever only going to draw the one rectangle?

Comment: I didn't clarify that my bad. One CustomLabelView that draws multiple rectangles on the same canvas.

Comment: OK, this is _very_ basic, but it shows how to add a rectangle (vertically) for each `addLabel()` call, starting with none: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tHpJWbZB43NZl1uCiKMDDU6COpP5tKBT.

Comment: Honestly, could've spent another 10 hours and wouldn't have figured that out...thanks a bunch mate. ```Invalidate(): Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future.```  Does it check if the other rectangles are already drawn, and draws the undrawn rectangles, or does it just redraw everything? I don't really get what it means by invalidate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you mean, but your `onDraw()` method needs to draw everything you need drawn each time it's called. You're basically starting with a blank `Canvas` each time `onDraw()` is called. The underlying, low-level stuff is probably doing some fancy, complicated tracking to minimize unnecessary draws, redraws, overdraws, etc., but that's nothing that your `View` would need to worry about.

Comment: Ahhhhh okay. Thanks for explaining everything really appreciate it. That's actually a question I had for a long time too.